# Encoding problems with Apache Velocity include

Tags: html, encoding, velocity

I have a velocity/html file.
I'm trying to include/parse some simple HTML into a page.

If I just copy the text directly on the the main file, it works fine:

> Miranda Kerr hasn’t been a Victoria’s
>   Secret Angel for ...

If I create a separate VM file, and include it like so:

```
#parse("topicoftheday/homepagenews.vm")
```

I get bad character garbage:

> Miranda Kerr hasnâ€™t been a
>   Victoriaâ€™s Secret Angel for

How? Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you have 3 encodings used,

1. The VM file in UTF-8.
2. The Velocity in Latin-1.
3. The terminal/JVM in ANSI.

You are using the non-ASCII apostrophe U+2019. The UTF-8 sequence is E2 80 19, happens to be the 3 chars you see in Latin-1 displayed as ANSI.

You need to change all of them to UTF-8 because Latin-1/ANSI don't have this character. Or you should use ASCII apostrophe '.

For velocity, set this parameter,

```
input.encoding = UTF-8
```

Comment: The content comes from an external RSS feed so I can't change the apostrophe. But I'm looking into changing the parameters ...

Comment: Where do we set that parameter?

Comment: @acdcjunior For example it is possible to pass properties in the constructor of VelocityEngine: 
    `private final Properties velocityEngineProperties = new Properties() {{
        put("input.encoding", CharEncoding.UTF_8);
    }};
    private final VelocityEngine velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine(velocityEngineProperties);`